# match color chart from rs value mysql php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I have question with google chart, is it possible to match the color of pie chart with value from recordset in mysql table

```
$fetchqry="SELECT
1219_set1.warna AS x,
round((Sum(cc)/1000),2) AS y,
kodewarna.nmwarna,
kodewarna.hexacolor
FROM
1219_set1
INNER JOIN kodewarna ON kodewarna.kdwarna = 1219_set1.warna
WHERE
1219_set1.thn = 2019 AND
1219_set1.bln = 11 AND
1219_set1.cabang = 'st'
GROUP BY
1219_set1.warna
";
```

there is hexa color there, and the google chart

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(initChart);

$(window).on("throttledresize", function (event) {
    initChart();
});

function initChart() {
    var options = {
      legend:'none',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        pieSliceText: 'percentage',
        colors: ['#0598d8', '#f97263'],
        chartArea: {
            left: "3%",
            top: "3%",
            height: "94%",
            width: "94%"
        }
    };

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Warna', 'Vol (L)'], <?php
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$fetchqry);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  echo "['".$row['x']."', ".$row['y']."],";
   } ?>  ]);

    drawChart(data, options)
}

function drawChart(data, options) {
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

where should i do to put var color inside script? please - thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the `colors` config option takes an array of colors
each color in the array will be assigned to a slice in the chart

so we just need to load the colors array,
in the same order as the data table.

we can do this by first, declaring our arrays for the data rows and colors

```
  var rows = [['Warna', 'Vol (L)']];
  var colors = [];
```

then loading each array from the sql result

```
  <?php
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$fetchqry);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      echo "rows.push(['".$row['x']."', ".$row['y']."]);";
      echo "colors.push('".$row['hexacolor']."');";
    }
  ?>
```

use the data rows array here...

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows);
```

and the colors array in the options, here...

```
  var options = {
    colors: colors,
```

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(initChart);

$(window).on('throttledresize', initChart);

function initChart() {
  var rows = [['Warna', 'Vol (L)']];
  var colors = [];

  <?php
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$fetchqry);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      echo "rows.push(['".$row['x']."', ".$row['y']."]);";
      echo "colors.push('".$row['hexacolor']."');";
    }
  ?>

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows);

  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    pieSliceText: 'percentage',
    colors: colors,
    chartArea: {
      left: "3%",
      top: "3%",
      height: "94%",
      width: "94%"
    }
  };

  drawChart(data, options)
}

function drawChart(data, options) {
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

---

**NOTE**

if you are using `jsapi` to load google charts,
this loader is out of date and should no longer be used.
instead use the following script file...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the `load` statement,
see above snippet...